# Swift loading more data repeats the already existing cell

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, web-services, uitableview

I'm using UITableview to load data from web service.
When viewDidLoad 10 cell are loaded, when user scroll down more data is loaded like Facebook application.

The problem is that on load more 10 extra cells should be loaded (numberOfRowInSection should be equal to 20) but instead the first 10 cells are repeated and than the news cell appear (i.e numberOfRowInSection is equal to 30)

example of what is happening

viewDidLoad:

A

B

C

when load more:

A

B

C

A

B

C

D

E

F

what I'm expecting is :

viewDidLoad:

A

B

C

when load more:

A

B

C

D

E

F

I'm getting data from web service  in this code:

```
                    if let infoDic = result.valueForKey("Info") as? NSDictionary {
                    globalVariables.gcurrentRun = (infoDic["CurrentRun"] as! String)
                        print("currentRun: \(globalVariables.gcurrentRun)")
                    globalVariables.gnextRun = (infoDic["NextRun"] as? String)!
                    if globalVariables.gcurrentRun == "1" {
                       sourceForImage = "news_icn"
                    }
                    else if globalVariables.gcurrentRun == "2" {
                       sourceForImage = "facebook_icon"
                    }
                    else if globalVariables.gcurrentRun == "3" {
                       sourceForImage = "twitter_icn"
                    }
                        print("nextRun: \(globalVariables.gnextRun)")
                    currentRunForLoadMore = globalVariables.gnextRun
                    if "\(infoDic["NoData"])" == 1 {
                    globalVariables.gnoData = "noMoreData"
                        print("noData: \(globalVariables.gnoData)")
                    } else {
                        globalVariables.gnoData = "moreData"
                        print("noData: \(globalVariables.gnoData)")
                    }
                    globalVariables.gpreviousRun = (infoDic["PreviousRun"] as? String)!
                        print("previousRun: \(globalVariables.gpreviousRun)")
                    currentRunForRefresh = globalVariables.gpreviousRun
                    globalVariables.gremark = (infoDic["Remark"] as? String)!
                        print("remark: \(globalVariables.gremark)")
                }

                if let mediaArray = result.valueForKey("mediaList") as? NSArray {
                    for media in mediaArray {
                        if globalVariables.gcurrentRun == "1" {
                    channel = ((media as? NSDictionary)!.valueForKey("Channel") as? String)!
                    print("channel: \(channel)")
                        }
                    globalVariables.gContentOfNews = ((media as? NSDictionary)!.valueForKey("Content") as? String)!
                    print("content: \(globalVariables.gContentOfNews)")
                        if globalVariables.gcurrentRun != "1" {
                            if let memberDic = (media.valueForKey("member") as? NSDictionary){
                               let memberFName = memberDic.valueForKey("Member_FName") as! String
                                channel = memberFName
                            }
                    print("fromName: \(channel)")
                        }
                    globalVariables.gIdFromWeb = Int((media.valueForKey("ID") as? String)!)!
                    globalVariables.gPublishD = ((media as? NSDictionary)!.valueForKey("PublishD") as? String)!
                    print("publishD: \(globalVariables.gPublishD)")
                    globalVariables.gPublishT = ((media as? NSDictionary)!.valueForKey("PublishT") as? String)!
                    print("publishTime: \(globalVariables.gPublishT)")

                        newsGrouped.append(NewsGrouped(channelOfNews: channel, publishedDate: globalVariables.gPublishD, publishedTime: globalVariables.gPublishT, contentOfNews: globalVariables.gContentOfNews, remarkSourceOfNews: "\(globalVariables.gTypeId)", newsIdFromWeb: globalVariables.gIdFromWeb, noDataToShow: globalVariables.gnoData))
                    do {
                        let bosId = try TeamDataHelper.insert(
                            NewsFeed(
                                newsId: 0,
                                typeId: Int(globalVariables.gcurrentRun)!,
                                idFromWeb: globalVariables.gIdFromWeb,
                                newInsertFlag: 1,
                                channel: channel,
                                fromName: globalVariables.gFromName,
                                contentOfNews: globalVariables.gContentOfNews,
                                publishD: globalVariables.gPublishD,
                                publishT: globalVariables.gPublishT
                            ))
                        print(bosId)
                    }
                }
                    completion(newsGrouped: newsGrouped)
            }
```

Here I'm code having the UITableview functions:

```
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    print("numberOfRows: \(newsGrouped.count)")
    return self.newsGrouped.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return  1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    loadActivityIndicator.stopAnimating()
   let newsCell: HPNewsWithImageTableViewCell = newsTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("hpNewsWithImageTableViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! HPNewsWithImageTableViewCell

        newsCell.idLbl.text = "\(newsGrouped[indexPath.section].newsIdFromWeb)"
        print("newsIdFromWeb: \(newsGrouped[indexPath.section].newsIdFromWeb)")
        newsCell.newsDate.text = newsGrouped[indexPath.section].publishedDate
        newsCell.userNameLbl.text = newsGrouped[indexPath.section].channelOfNews
        print("globalVariables.gChannel: \(newsGrouped[indexPath.section].channelOfNews)")

        newsCell.imageOfSource.image = UIImage(named: "\(newsGrouped[indexPath.section].sourceImage)")
        print("imageOfSource: \(newsGrouped[indexPath.section].sourceImage)")
        newsCell.newsTime.text = newsGrouped[indexPath.section].publishedTime

        print(newsGrouped[indexPath.section].publishedTime)
        newsCell.newsText.text = newsGrouped[indexPath.section].contentOfNews
        print(newsGrouped[indexPath.section].contentOfNews)
            newsCell.selectionStyle = .None
    do {
    try TeamDataHelper.update()
        }
    catch {
    }
    return newsCell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 170
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("newsDetailsSegue", sender: self)
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 1.5
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 5
}

func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let offsetY = scrollView.contentOffset.y
    let contentHeight = scrollView.contentSize.height
    if offsetY > contentHeight - scrollView.frame.size.height {
        loadMoreIndicator.hidden = false
        loadMoreIndicator.startAnimating()
        CallForNewsAPICalls.GetNewsFeeds(actionDown, CurrentRun: currentRunForLoadMore) { (newsGrouped) -> Void in
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                for news in newsGrouped {
                    print("currentRunForLoadMore\(currentRunForLoadMore)")
                    self.newsGrouped.append(news)
                }
                self.newsTableView.reloadData()
            })
        }

    }
}
```

note that i'm using local data

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you show some code snippets? I think that you have something wrong when appending data to your array...

Comment: What is the output of this line: `print("numberOfRows: \(newsGrouped.count)")` after the second request?

Comment: on viewDidLoad: numberOfRows: 10  when i load more data: numberOfRows: 30 then it becomes automatically without loading more numberOfRows: 60 and it continues till it reaches numberOfRows: 4772 @MaxPevsner

Comment: One way you can adopt like, before adding the data to the array, remove all objects, then add the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your server returns you all the data.

Before appending the new data

```
newsGrouped.append(NewsGrouped(channelOfNews: channel, publishedDate: globalVariables.gPublishD, publishedTime: globalVariables.gPublishT, contentOfNews: globalVariables.gContentOfNews, remarkSourceOfNews: "\(globalVariables.gTypeId)", newsIdFromWeb: globalVariables.gIdFromWeb, noDataToShow: globalVariables.gnoData))
```

clean the `newsGrouped` array.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but i have got an empty table.

Comment: oh i have noticed something that the very next 10 cell after the first load more are skipped with the other 10 cells. the first one after the new 10 cells is repeated 3 times

Comment: also the data is not set in order

Comment: @R.AlAli put a breakpoint on the line mentioned in my answer and check what values `newsGrouped` have each time it's hit.

Comment: Thank you cleaning the newsGrouped array is the solution

Answer (score 0):

In order to make sure you only load at last row, you can use `willDisplayCell`. Check if current row is equal to total count or array, then start load new data

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if indexPath.row == self.yourArray.count - 1 {
        // fetch your data here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just store previous data in one array l.e. like **storeArray**  and when u load others, **append** that one to storeArray and use **sotreArray** to tableview ...